# OpenMPI works on cluster but Intel MPI asks for password

Tags: ssh, mpi

I'm trying to setup a cluster and have successfully been able to connect to the nodes using SSH without a password and run some scripts using Openmpi.  However when I try to connect using COMSOLs built in intelMPI it still asks for a password.

The only way I was able to get openMPI to work was to have the hostfile be in the form of hostname@ip, however the mpd_hosts file I have for the intelMPI doesn't like that.  Any ideas?

Comment: If you try to ssh to one of the nodes in your host file, are you asked for a password? If so, you may need to setup an ssh keypair to allow your user access without a password.

Comment: No I can access all the nodes without a password.  I've also been able to get openmpi to work. The SSH is very picky about how I connect thought, it has to be node1@ip address, which the IntelMPI host file I'm trying to setup doesn't allow.  Is there a setting in SSH where I can just type in the node name for it to accept?

Comment: It's possible the default process manager in your IntelMPI is not using ssh to launch processes. Check to see if there is an mpiexec.hydra executable in your IntelMPI bin directory and try that.